# How to use SQL IN with a string containing a comma separated list?

Tags: postgresql

For a single value it works fine when I cast it to text:

```
WHERE product_id::text in (inputProduct_ids)
```

But I have problems if there is more than one value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ourFunction(text) { 
    inputProduct_ids text := $1;

    SELECT STRING_AGG(product_id::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY product_id)
    INTO product_ids 
    FROM product_table
    WHERE product_id in ('||inputProduct_ids||');
}

select ourFunction('573, 574 , 575 , 576 , 579 , 580 ,581 , 584');
```

Comment: i am new to this platform. need to learn how to post question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to pass the argument as a string, you can cast it to an array of `integer` in the query:

```
SELECT string_agg(product_id::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY product_id)
INTO product_ids 
FROM product_table
WHERE product_id =ANY (CAST('{' || $1 || '}' AS integer[]));
```

The `=ANY` operator can be used with arrays and does the same as `IN` (in fact the optimizer translates `IN` into `=ANY` internally).

As a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, you can also use `string_to_array` instead of a type cast:

```
WHERE CAST(product_id AS text) =ANY (string_to_array($1, ','))
```

Comment: `string_to_array()` is faster in my experience than casting - at least for long strings

Comment: Thnak you so much for quick response..! in my case product_id is bigint and i am getting number of ids with comma separated and i need to pick only those ids that are present in the product table in a postgres function.  can you help me correct this : select * from product_table where product_id = ANY ( select string_to_array('588,586,589',','));

Comment: It should work just like I wrote. If you want to use an index on `product_id`, either use the first variant or use the second one with a cast on the right hand side.

Comment: Thank you so much Laurenz Albe and a_horse_with_no_name . you guys are genius.